# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

I have set up PHP, MySQL, and Apache. `localhost()` for PHP and it is working well. But after I downloaded MySQL, it reports:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you restart apache after you installed the packages?

Comment: http://nz.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php

Comment: You tagged your question [mysql-error-1064] - how do you get that if your script can't communicate with MySQL?

Comment: read this article http://www.somacon.com/p109.php , this may help you

Comment: If mysqli or PDO works then you're better off using them instead anyway.

Comment: @GordonM is quite right.  The `mysql_*` functions [are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).  There are [better alternatives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) that support [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 69):

You upgraded to PHP 7, and now `mysql_connect` is deprecated.  Check yours with:

```
php -version
```

Change it to `mysqli_connect` as in:

```
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$pass = "foobar";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pass, "your_database");
```

If you're upgrading legacy PHP, now you're faced with the task of upgrading all your `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli_*` functions.

Answer (score 39):

If you get this error after upgrading to PHP 7.0, then you are using deprecated libraries.

> mysql_connect — Open a connection to a MySQL Server 
>   Warning 
>    This
>   extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

More here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer - it's bad practice to still be using mysql_* calls.

Answer (score 36):

Open your terminal and run bellow command.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

If you are running PHP you will also need to install the php module for mysql 5:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Answer (score 8):

Verify that your installation of PHP has been compiled with mysql support. Create a test web page containing `<?php phpinfo(); exit(); ?>` and load it in your browser. Search the page for MySQL. If you don't see it, you need to recompile PHP with MySQL support, or reinstall a PHP package that has it built-in

Comment: I have similar problem, I don't see any MySQL in my test page: https://jsfiddle.net/ad0gd90y/. Instead I saw only "mysqlnd". Should I install MySQL prior to PHP? How do I recompile PHP with MySQL supprt? @RohitKumarChoudhary

Comment: Mysqlnd is the native driver of PHP for mysql. Have you installed mysql in your system?

Answer (score 7):

```
PHP.INI
```

Check if you forgot to enable the options below(loads the modules for mysql among others):

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Answer (score 6):

Use.
`<?php $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database'); ?>`

In PHP 7.
You probably have PHP 7 in XAMPP. You now have two option: MySQLi and PDO.

Answer (score 6):

For *CPanel* users, if you see this error and you already have PHP 5.x selected for the site, there might be a *CPanel* update that disabled `mysql` and `mysqli` PHP extensions.

To check and enable the extensions:

1. Go to *Select PHP Version* in *CPanel*
2. Make sure you have PHP 5.x selected
3. Make sure `mysql` and `mysqli` PHP extensions are checked

Answer (score 4):

This error is coming only for your PHP version v7.0.
you can avoid these using PHP v5.0
else

use it

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")
```

i made only mysqli from mysql

Answer (score 3):

A solution could be to use adapter functions like these to start using `mysqli` instead of `mysql` over your entire application:

```
if (!function_exists('mysql_connect')) {
    function mysql_connect($host = '', $user = '', $password = '', $database = '', $port = 0, $socket = '') {
        return mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database, $port, $socket);
    }
}


if (!function_exists('mysql_select_db')) {
    function mysql_select_db($link, $dbname) {
        mysqli_select_db($link, $dbname);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem on RHEL6.  It turns out that the mysql.ini file in /etc/php.d only had a module name but needed a full path name.  On my RHEL6 system the entry that works is:

```
; Enable mysql extension module

extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so
```

After modifying the file, I restarted apache and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is here (I needed just to remove the last slash (NB: backward slashes) from `PHPIniDir 'c:\PHP\'`): [Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() cannot solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221364/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect-cannot-solve/18871425#18871425)

Answer (score 1):

Am using windows 8 n this issue got resolved by changing the environment variables

follow these steps:
Open my computer properties->advanced system settings->Environment variables.
Under 'system variables', select 'path' and click on 'edit'
In 'variable value', add 'C:\php;' OR the path where php installed.

click OK and apply the settings and restart the system.
It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick fix:

All the pros will probably hate me for this answer. But I got the same error on a server: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()** that was using PHP 7. Did not have time to rewrite all the mysql code so a quick, temporary fix if anyone needs it is in CPANEL to look for **PHP Configuration** and change the version for that account to something like PHP 5.4 instead of PHP 7. Then the code worked fine without the above error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows10, PHP 7.2 and try to connect to mysql.
If this error occurred

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli() in

The do the following steps to get it correct.

1. Go to the PHP installation folder,
2. CHeck for php.ini file, (Only dev, prod file is there, then one of the file as php.ini file)
3. Look for "extension=mysqli" and remove the ";" before it.
4. Look for "extension_dir" and mentioned the path of "ext" directory.
5. Restart the application.

Hope this helps to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Check if mysqli module is installed for your PHP version

```
$ ls /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysql*
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysqli.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysqlnd.ini
```

Enable the module

```
$ sudo phpenmod mysqli
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code Can Help You

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";


$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

?>
```

But Change The "servername","username" and "password"

Answer (score 0):

The problem shows up when you're using `mysql_connect` in your code lines so just add it as in `mysqli_connect` and it will solve the problem.
You also have to then use `mysqli` throughout your code lines or the problem would surface again.
The example `mysql_select_db` will then be `mysqli_select_db` for selecting Database.