# PHP.INI file paths don't seem to work right

Tags: php, apache

I have an apache webserver with PHP and I got PHP setup fine, but I can't get the relative directories to work right. When I set `extension_dir` like the second line, it can't load the modules, but when I set it using the first it works fine.

```
extension_dir = "C:\ArlenWebServer\PHP\ext"
extension_dir = ".\ext"
```

http.conf looks like this:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/ArlenWebServer/PHP/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/ArlenWebServer/PHP"
```

How does the PHP INI file work and what should I do different?

Apache 2.4, PHP 5.4.14

My directory structure looks like this:

```
/ArlenWebServer
    /Apache24
        /bin
        /conf
        /htdocs
    /PHP
        /ext
        php.ini
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "\ext" without a dot ? .

Comment: It's not relative to `PHPiniDir`, but Apaches startup or working directory then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, this works as well: `extension_dir = "..\..\PHP\ext"`.

See my update with directory structure.

It appears to be relative to `httpd.exe`. The next line in my ini file was `error_log = ".\errors.log"`, and there is a PHP errors.log in the bin directory.

So, is it relative to the bin directory.

Comment: You sir, are a life saver. I've been pulling my hair out as to why relative paths never worked with `extension_dir`.