# mysql_connect CHANGE TO mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have some existing PHP code that is now throwing a fatal error since we migrated to PHP 7.0.  Using this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615436/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect) I've altered this line:

```
$link = mysql_connect($host.':'.$port, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
```

to this:

```
$link = new mysqli($host.':'.$port, $user, $pass);
```

I am now throwing this error which I guess is some progress.  The syntax seems fine?  What am I missing?

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out
```

Comment: Did you try `$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket);` as per http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just using the function.

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db).
```

The order is host, user, pass, db

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: What about the port?

Comment: mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);

Answer (score 1):

The constructor class looks like this:

```
__construct (
    [ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host") 
    [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") 
    [, string $passwd = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") 
    [, string $dbname = "" 
    [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") 
    [, string $socket = ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )
```

So the order is `host, username, password, database, port, socket`.  You'll need to pass in the port in a separate variable:

```
$link = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, null, $port);
```

Edited because I copied the wrong bit of code..