# Parse error: Invalid numeric literal application\config\constants.php on line 43

Tags: codeigniter

Parse error: Invalid numeric literal in C:\xampp\htdocs\aecollegealumni.com\application\config\constants.php on line 43

in constant file i have define('std',021)
and showing above error. i am using xammp server 3.2.2, php 7.1.1 and apache 2.4

can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

to

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Comment: How you calling, could you please share and let me know is it Codeigniter Framework?

Comment: it's seem error not because of this.
Go to the "application/config/database.php" define your db credentials there.

Comment: yes sir it s codeigniter framework.. application/config/constants.php line number 43 define('std',091)..                         define('FILE_READ_MODE', 0644);

define('FILE_WRITE_MODE', 0666);

define('DIR_READ_MODE', 0755);

define('DIR_WRITE_MODE', 0777);

define('EzaypayAuthcode', 'de4527cfd9674f86b');

define('AccNo', 1400050241);

define('std', 091);

Comment: This error is not because of this define.
go to the application/config/database.php

change 
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';  TO
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';

Comment: yes sir assigned but still it is showing error... it was working fine in php 5.6 now i have installed php7.1.1. so it is not supporting in this

Comment: Ahh!! ok , go with this link maybe it can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615436/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect

Answer (score 0):

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\aecollegealumni.com\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php:74 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\aecollegealumni.com\system\database\DB_driver.php(231): CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_connect() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\aecollegealumni.com\system\database\DB.php(297): CI_DB_driver->initialize() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\aecollegealumni.com\application\core\MY_Loader.php(43): DB(Array, NULL) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\aecollegealumni.com\system\core\Loader.php(2343): MY_Loader->database() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\aecollegealumni.com\system\core\Loader.php(305): CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader() #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\aecollegealumni.com\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php(123): CI_Loader->initialize() #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\aecollegealumni.com\system\core\Controller.php(103): MX_Loader->initialize() #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\aecollegealumni.com\application\controllers\home.php(6): CI_Controller->__construct() #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\aecollegealumni.com\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(617): H in C:\xampp\htdocs\aecollegealumni.com\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php on line 74

Comment: sorry it is define('std', 091)

Comment: **091** is not a valid **Octal** number hence you are getting error.